# ¿Es correcto usar "sino" al final de una oración?

Tags: gramática

¿Es correcta la siguiente oración?

> El canal ya no emite con ese formato en las noticias. Cámbialo. **Va a parecer viejo sino.**

O, por el contrario, ¿es lo correcto utilizar 'si no'?

> Va a parecer viejo si no.

Comment: La afirmación me parece incompleta. ¿Tienes más contexto?

Comment: @Ustanak "El canal ya no emite con ese formato en las noticias. Cámbialo. Va a parecer viejo sino"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Sino* es una conjunción adversativa, mientras que *si no* es una secuencia conformada por la conjunción *si* seguida del adverbio de negación *no* y que en este caso significa "de lo contrario" o "de otra forma". En la frase que mencionas tiene este último sentido, pues puede decirse:

> *"Cámbialo. De lo contrario, parecerá viejo"*

o bien

> *"Cámbialo. Si no (lo haces), parecerá viejo."*

o demás construcciones por el estilo. El hecho de que esté al final en la frase no significa que deba escribirse diferente.
El *Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas* tiene un [artículo que explica el uso de *sino*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=sino).